# How to use shapeless HList to have a list of the same type but with a different generic?

Tags: scala, types, shapeless

I need to define a type as a list of `Action[T >: MyType]` where `MyType` for now is equivalent to `Any` but it might change.

A `List[Action[T]]` doesn't fit for many cases and the compiler can't solve it.

So I thought I could use an `HList` but I'm really noob with it.

I started with `type ListOfAction = HList` but I want the elements of my list to be all `Action` but I don't know how to specify that the list should look like `Action[Double]`, `Action[Int]`, `Action[String]`, ... and not only possible type.

Comment: What do you mean with *define a type as a list of `Action[T:>MyType]`* ? How would you use a lower type bound in a type ?

Comment: Something like `type Action[T:>MyType]=(T)=>T`

Comment: It compiles but I want a `HList` that contains only `Action` elements but I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to encode that as a type. But using shapeless you could write a function that will only accept the type of HList that you mention.

Since you didn't provide your definition for Action, I'll use this one:

```
case class Action[+T <: MyType](value: T)
```

And for some MyType inhabitants we'll use this:

```
trait MyType
case class MyString(string: String) extends MyType
case class MyInt(int: Int) extends MyType
```

Now using the LUBConstraint from shapeless we can now restrict that all elements of an HList have the same supertype:

```
def accept[L <: HList](hlist: L)
                      (implicit ev: LUBConstraint[L, Action[MyType]]) = println(hlist)
```

Now, you can try this:

```
accept(Action(MyString("string")) :: Action(MyInt(1)) :: HNil)
```

While this:

```
accept(Action(MyString("string")) :: 1 :: HNil)
```

Will fail to compile.

Note that you need to define the `T` in Action as `+T` and changed the `:>` to `<:`, otherwise you won't get the subtype relation.